# How to stop a Transaction in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to stop a transaction if an if condition fails?

I want this transaction to stop if `IF (@dela = '01-01-2013')` is true, but instead it raises the error and procedes with the `Update` execution.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_AdaugareModificareOfertaSpeciala
ON OferteSpeciale
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN TRAN T1;
DECLARE @dela DATETIME;
SET @dela = (SELECT dela FROM INSERTED);

IF (UPDATE(codP) OR UPDATE(codM) OR UPDATE(dela))
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Nu se poate modifica cheia primara.', 1, 1);
ROLLBACK TRAN T1;
END

SAVE TRANSACTION T1;
IF (@dela = '01-01-2013')
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Data nu este corecta.', 1, 1);
ROLLBACK TRAN T1;
END
```

Example where `dela = '01-01-2013':`

```
UPDATE OferteSpeciale SET pret = 23.69 where codP = 'P1' and codM = 'M1';
```

It raises the error but also makes the update.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know that SQL Server DML triggers are **always** set based and not row based. So, `inserted` and `deleted` tables may contain **more rows**, not just one row.

If you want to cancel the update/insert statement when `(@dela = '01-01-2013')` then you could use this condition:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE dela = '20130101')
BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
RAISERROR('The starting date is wrong', 16, 1);
END
```

Note 1: [SMALL]DATE[TIME][2] constants should follow ISO8601 rules: `yyyymmdd`, `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss` or `yyyy-mm-dd`, `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`.

Note 2: The error message from

```
IF (UPDATE(codP) OR UPDATE(codM) OR UPDATE(dela))
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Nu se poate modifica cheia primara.', 1, 1);
ROLLBACK TRAN T1;
END
```

is misleading if the PK doesn't contains codP, codM and dela columns.

Note 3: The severity level for RAISERROR statement should be 16 not 1. A RAISERROR statement with a severity level equal to 1 is pretty much like the PRINT statement.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could do this with an [INSTEAD OF UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288.aspx)  trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_AdaugareModificareOfertaSpeciala
ON OferteSpeciale
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @dela DATETIME;
SET @dela = (SELECT dela FROM INSERTED);

IF (UPDATE(codP) OR UPDATE(codM) OR UPDATE(dela)) BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Nu se poate modifica cheia primara.', 1, 1);
END

ELSE IF (@dela = '01-01-2013') BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Data nu este corecta.', 1, 1);
END
ELSE BEGIN 
    UPDATE o SET dela = i.dela, codm = i.codm, codp = i.codp, pret = i.pret-- add rest of columns here
    FROM OferteSpeciale o
        JOIN Inserted i ON o.[Primarykey] = i.[Primarykey]
END
```

Answer (score 1):

By default transactions are auto committed but you can `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;` and then at the end of your query you can `COMMIT T1;` Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms187807%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).